# Rails: list all attributes that can't be mass assigned

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I am working through an old legacy project that has recently been updated. The models to the project are in an engine running separate from the controllers and views etc. The engine is running on rails 4.1.6 while the controllers etc are on Rails 3.

This has led to many issues with mass-assignment. I have created a little module that reads the db columns and white lists the attributes for that model. However in a case such as this NewsItem model  which has associations and needs to accept attributes for those associations, the module doesn't work.

```
class Newsitem < ActiveRecord::Base

  include MyAttrAccessibleModule

  has_and_belongs_to_many :assets
  has_and_belongs_to_many :boroughs
  has_and_belongs_to_many :venues
```

I need to add

```
  attr_accessible :asset1_attachment_remove, 
                  :asset1_attachment_title, 
                  :asset2_attachment_title, 
                  :asset3_attachment_title, 
                  :asset4_attachment_title, 
                  :borough_ids, 
                  :venue_ids
```

But finding all models that require this is a bit of a pain, seeing as there are well over 100.

Is there a way to highlight, find, test, discover in what other models this error might occur in also?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for could be this:

```
Object.attributes.keys - Object.accessible_attributes
```

This should subtract all the whitelisted attributes from all of the available ones.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Stefan Dorunga for his suggestion. It led me in the right direction.

```
if reflect_on_all_associations(:has_and_belongs_to_many).any?
  association = reflect_on_all_associations(:has_and_belongs_to_many)
  association.each {|model| attr_accessible model.plural_name.singularize + "_id"}
  association.each {|model| attr_accessible model.plural_name}
end
```

I query the model to see if it has a relationship where the relation id isnt explicitly listed and generate it dynamically.

The only downside is that I have to include the module after all the listed associations. I usually include modules at the top of a class. Whether this is standard practice or not I do not know.